# Conditionals for data type in gnuplot functions

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to define a function which returns the string "NaN" or sprintf("%g",val) depending on whether val is a string or a numeric value. Initially I was trying to test if val was defined (using the gnuplot "exists" function) but it seems that I cannot pass any undefined variable to a function (an error is issued before the function is evaluated). Therefore: is there a way to test inside a function whether the argument is a string or numeric?

I search for a function isstring which I can use somehow like

```
myfunc(val)=(isstring(val)?"NaN":sprintf("%g",val))
```

The goal is to output the values of variables without risking errors in case they are undefined. However I need it as a function if I want a compact code for many variables.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  The two functions you are describing are entirely different.  You have the method using `exists` and the method where you are trying to test if something is a number.  What are you actually trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: No. The method of using exists inside the function was my first trial. It will not work since an undefined variable cannot be passed to any function (as far as I understand now). The remaining possibility is to destinguish (e.g.) val="undefined" from val=1.0 and to test inside the function if val is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnuplot doesn't really have the introspection abilities that many other languages have.  In fact, it treats strings and numbers (at least integers) very similarly:

```
print "1"+2  #prints 3
a=1
print "foo".a  #prints foo1
```

I'm not exactly sure how this is implemented internally.  However, what you're asking is very tricky to get to work.

Actually, I think your first attempt (checking if a variable exists) is more sensible as type-checking in gnuplot is impossible*.  You can pass the variable name to the function as a string, but the problem is that you don't seem to have a handle on the value. All seems lost -- But wait, gnuplot has an `eval` statement which when given a string will evaluate it.  This seems great!  Unfortunately, it's a statement, not a function (so it can't be used in a function -- argv!).  The best solution I can come up with is to write a function which returns an expression that can be evaluated using `eval`.  Here goes:

```
def exists_func(result,var)=sprintf("%s=exists('%s')?sprintf('%g',var):'NaN'",result,var,var)
```

Now when you want to use it, you just prefix it with `eval`

```
a=3
eval exists_func("my_true_result","a")
print my_true_result #3
eval exists_func("my_false_result","b")
print my_false_result #NaN
```

This goes against the grain a little bit.  In most programming languages, you'd probably want to do something like this:

```
my_true_result=exists_func(a)
```

But alas, I can't figure out how to make that form work.

Of course, the same thing goes here that always goes with `eval`.  Don't use this function with untrusted strings.

<sub>*I don't actually know that it's impossible, but I've never been able to get it to work</sub>

**EDIT**

In response to your comment above on the question, I think a function like this would be a little more intuitive:

```
def fmt(x)=(x==x)?sprintf("%g",x):"NaN"
```

With this function, your "sentinal/default" value should be `NaN` instead of `"undefined"`, but it doesn't seem like this should make too much of a difference...(Really, if you're willing to live with `"nan"` instead of `"NaN"` you don't need this function at all -- `sprintf` will do just fine.  (Note that this works because according to IEEE, `NaN` doesn't equal anything (even itself)).

Comment: Yes, I think in view of the alternatives the best solution is to initialize all relevant variables to NaN - though this means I need to change other parts of the script which are based on exist conditionals. I will still need the output function as it is slightly more complicated than `sprintf("%g",var)`

Comment: @highsciguy -- This is why I asked what your intentions were in the beginning :).  Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You helped me a lot these days with gnuplot. I want to give you something back because I have found a solution to check if a variable is numeric or not. This helps to decide which operators can be used on it (e.g. == for numbers, eq for strings).

The solution is not very simple, but it works. It redirects gnuplot's print command to a temp file, writes the variable to the file with `print myvar` and evaluates the file's first line with `system("perl -e '<isnumeric(line#1 in temp file)?>' ")` (<> is pseudo-code). Let me know if there's room for imrpovements and let me hear your suggestions!

Example: myvar is a float. Any integer (1 or "1") or string value ("*") works too!

```
myvar = -2.555  
 # create temporary file for checking if variables are numeric  
Int_tmpfle = "tmp_isnumeric_check"  
 # redirect print output into temp file (existing file is overwritten)  
set print Int_tmpfle    
 # save variable's value to file  
print myvar             
 # check if file is numeric with Perl's 'looks_like_number' function   
isnumeric = system("perl -e 'use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number); \  
open(FLE,".Int_tmpfle."); $line = < FLE >; \  
if (looks_like_number($line) > 0) {print qq(y)} ' ")  
 # reset print output to < STDOUT> (terminal)  
set print "-"           
 # make sure to use "," when printing string and numeric values  
if (isnumeric eq "y") {print myvar," is numeric."} else {print myvar," is not numeric."}
```